# How to calculate distance from RSSI and TXPower?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I have searched lot of but could not get result or not even know is that result correct or not.

I do have BLE which sends RSSI and TXPower. Actually I am trying to find distance with value of RSSI and and TXPower but can't get correct one. I have followed [this](https://gist.github.com/eklimcz/446b56c0cb9cfe61d575) and also [this](https://iotandelectronics.wordpress.com/2016/10/07/how-to-calculate-distance-from-the-rssi-value-of-the-ble-beacon/) as well but don't know which one is correct. What will be the correct formula to get distance from RSSI and TXPower